# Is Office.context.ui.messageParent broken in Outlook 2016 for Windows?

Tags: windows, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I'm troubleshooting an issue where a pop-up created by an Outlook add-in isn't communicating to its parent when using `Office.context.ui.messageParent()` in the Outlook desktop client for Windows.

The issue started occurring after a Windows 10 update (1903). The Outlook desktop client version I'm using is: 16.0.12026.20344. I'm loading the Office JS Api through the CDN provided in their Github repo.

Initially, I thought it was a lack of registering the correct events on the pop-up window but the event raised (`dialogEventReceived`) when the pop-up window is closed is registered and handled correctly.

There are no logged errors after calling `Office.context.ui.messageParent()`.

I've made sure that the pop-up window (handling authentication in this case) is correctly loading the Office JS api and is initializing.

All applicable app domains have been correctly listed in the add-in's manifest file.

```
Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(fullUrl,
    {
        height: 60,
        width: 20,
        displayInIframe: false
    }, function (asyncResult) {
        if (asyncResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
                //showNotification(asyncResult.error.code = ": " + asyncResult.error.message);
            } else {
            dialog = asyncResult.value;
            dialog.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogMessageReceived, processMessage);
            dialog.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogEventReceived, processDialogEvent);
        }
    });

Office.initialize = function() {
  console.log('oauth2 redirect');
  debugger;
  Office.context.ui.messageParent(window.location.href);
};
```

The expected behavior is that the pop-up raises the `dialogMessageReceived` event.

Comment: Can you also add the version information for Outlook 2016 (and check that it is up-to-date)? And can you check whether the add-in is loading Office.js from appsforoffice.microsoft.com, or if it is used a packaged version? Thanks.

Comment: I'm using Outlook 2016 version 16.0.12026.20344 and Office.js is beling loaded from appsforoffice.microsoft.com.

Comment: We have fixed a bug in build 16.0.12105.10000 that we believe will address your issue with Office.context.ui.messageParent. It should be released this month, so please lookout for the update to get the bug fix.